# How can I grab the entire body text from a web page using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to grab some text from a webpage of a medical document for a Natural Language Processing project and am having issues extracting the necessary information using BeautifulSoup.  The website I am viewing can be found at the address:  https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2332-Abdominal%20Abscess%20I&D

What I would like to do is grab the entire text body from this page and doing so with my cursor and simply applying a copy/paste would give me the appropriate text I am interested in:

```
Sample Type / Medical Specialty: Gastroenterology
Sample Name: Abdominal Abscess I&D
Description: Incision and drainage (I&D) of abdominal abscess, excisional debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and muscle, then removal of foreign body.
(Medical Transcription Sample Report)
PREOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS: Abdominal wall abscess.

... (body text) ...

The finished wound size was 9.0 x 5.3 x 5.2 cm in size. Patient tolerated the procedure well. Dressing was applied, and he was taken to recovery room in stable condition.
```

However, I would like to implement this using BeautifulSoup because I would like to perform a loop to grab multiple medical documents from the same website.

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2332-Abdominal%20Abscess%20I&D')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id':'sampletext'})

# Here I am able to specify the <h1> tag to get 'Sample Type / Medical Specialty' as well as 'Sample Name' text fields

record.find('h1').text.replace('\n', ' ')
```

However, I cannot replicate this for the remaining text (i.e. Description, PREOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS, POSTOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS, Procedure, etc.) as there are no unique tags to identify these text fields

If anyone is familiar with web-scraping concepts using BeautifulSoup I would appreciate any feedback!  Again my goal is to obtain the full text from the webpage which I would ultimately like to add to a Pandas Dataframe.  Thanks!

Comment: They didn't design this web page with any semantic markup, it's just a big blob of text with bold headings.

Comment: @Barmar So I am basically out of luck if I wanted to scrape each document?  I can do it the old fashioned way by copy and pasting the text into a csv, although this seems quite inefficient...

Comment: Use `soup.find('body').text` to get the text of the entire document.

Comment: @Barmar That is quite helpful although it looks like I'll still need to do some additional cleaning for the document given the output

Comment: Exactly. For this web page, it's almost not worth using BS, you might as well parse it with regular expressions.

Comment: @Barmer I'm struggling with how to parse this correctly.  I'm attempting to use regex in the following way:  `re.match(r'(Sample Type / Medical Specialty).*\.(adsbygoogle)$', body_text)`.  Clearly this is wrong but hopefully I get my point across that I'm trying to find a common start and stop of the body text.  If you have any feedback or pointers on how to implement this I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it took me a while, but there isn't an easy way of extracting usable text unless you manually iterate over all elements:

```py
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag, NavigableString, Comment

url = 'https://www.mtsamples.com/site/pages/sample.asp?Type=24-Gastroenterology&Sample=2332-Abdominal%20Abscess%20I&D'
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
html = res.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

so far nothing special.

```py
title_el = soup.find('h1')
page_title = title_el.text.strip()
first_hr = title_el.find_next_sibling('hr')

description_title = title_el.find_next_sibling('b', text=re.compile('description', flags=re.I))
description_text_parts = []
for s in description_title.next_siblings:
    if s is first_hr:
        break
    if isinstance(s, Tag):
        description_text_parts.append(s.text.strip())
    elif isinstance(s, NavigableString):
        description_text_parts.append(str(s).strip())
description_text = '\n'.join(p for p in description_text_parts if p.strip())
```

here we get `page_title` from `<h1>`

```
'Sample Type / Medical Specialty:  Gastroenterology\nSample Name: Abdominal Abscess I&D'
```

and `description` by walking the elements after we see the text `Description:`.

```
'Incision and drainage (I&D) of abdominal abscess, excisional debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and muscle, then removal of foreign body.\n(Medical Transcription Sample Report)'
```

Now, all titles are placed under the horizontal rule:

```py
# titles are all bold and uppercase
titles = [b for b in first_hr.find_next_siblings('b') if b.text.strip().isupper()]
```

We find the text between the titles and assign it to the title we see earlier

```
docs = []
for t in titles:
    text_parts = []
    for s in t.next_siblings:
        # go until next title
        if s in titles:
            break
        if isinstance(s, Comment):
            continue
        if isinstance(s, Tag):
            if s.name == 'div':
                break
            text_parts.append(s.text.strip())
        elif isinstance(s, NavigableString):
            text_parts.append(str(s).strip())
    text = '\n'.join(p for p in text_parts if p.strip())
    docs.append({
        'title': t.text.strip(),
        'text': text
    })
```

printing docs gives:

```py
[
{'title': 'PREOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS:', 'text': 'Abdominal wall abscess.'}, 
{'title': 'POSTOPERATIVE DIAGNOSIS:', 'text': 'Abdominal wall abscess.'}, 
{'title': 'PROCEDURE:', 'text': 'Incision and drainage (I&D) of abdominal abscess, excisional debridement of nonviable and viable skin, subcutaneous tissue and muscle, then removal of foreign body.'}, 
{'title': 'ANESTHESIA:', 'text': 'LMA.'}, 
{'title': 'INDICATIONS:', 'text': 'Patient is a pleasant 60-year-old gentleman, who initially had a sigmoid colectomy for diverticular abscess, subsequently had a dehiscence with evisceration.  Came in approximately 36 hours ago with pain across his lower abdomen.  CT scan demonstrated presence of an abscess beneath the incision.  I recommended to the patient he undergo the above-named procedure.  Procedure, purpose, risks, expected benefits, potential complications, alternatives forms of therapy were discussed with him, and he was agreeable to surgery.'}, 
{'title': 'FINDINGS:', 'text': 'The patient was found to have an abscess that went down to the level of the fascia.  The anterior layer of the fascia was fibrinous and some portions necrotic.  This was excisionally debrided using the Bovie cautery, and there were multiple pieces of suture within the wound and these were removed as well.'},
{'title': 'TECHNIQUE:', 'text': 'Patient was identified, then taken into the operating room, where after induction of appropriate anesthesia, his abdomen was prepped with Betadine solution and draped in a sterile fashion.  The wound opening where it was draining was explored using a curette.  The extent of the wound marked with a marking pen and using the Bovie cautery, the abscess was opened and drained.  I then noted that there was a significant amount of undermining.  These margins were marked with a marking pen, excised with Bovie cautery; the curette was used to remove the necrotic fascia.  The wound was irrigated; cultures sent prior to irrigation and after achievement of excellent hemostasis, the wound was packed with antibiotic-soaked gauze.  A dressing was applied.  The finished wound size was 9.0 x 5.3 x 5.2 cm in size.  Patient tolerated the procedure well.  Dressing was applied, and he was taken to recovery room in stable condition.'}
]
```